# How can I query my Core Spotlight indices?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, spotlight, corespotlight

Is it possible to query my own app's Core Spotlight indices? I want to avoid re-indexing entries (as they require pulling thumbnails from the network), and am unsure about what assumptions I can make about the state of the index after certain events such as app reinstall, device restore, a user disabling/enabling Core Spotlight results for my app or device, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: apparently not.